# Reading a .java file in Java

Tags: java, file

I would like to make a test that reads a .java file in my Java project and converts it to a `String`.  How can I do this inside a JUnit test (no command line args)?

Comment: 'parsing' does not mean what you think it means.  That would imply converting the file to Java byte code or an AST.  What have you tried and what problems are you having?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want your JUnit test to directly parse a java file?

Comment: I am not sure on classpaths for .java files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieved the current working dir and navigated from there to the java file.

```
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place the .java file at a known location and use absolute/relative path in `File` to access the file

Or use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` to access it [based on classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: for example:
com.abc.MyClass.java

What would I pass into getResourceAsStream()?

Comment: if com is accessible from the classpath, you sould be able to access it as `getResourceAsStream("/com/abc/MyClass.java")` assuming it is the com/abc/ folder hierarchy.  If it is actually named com.abc.MyClass.java, use `getResourceAsStream("/com.abc.MyClass.java")`

Comment: You can load any file this way.  Are you creating a .jar that you are running?  If yes, you need to add the .java to that jar before `getResourceAsStream` can work.

Comment: So use `File`, as clearly `getResourceAsStream` is not the right approach for you in this case.

Comment: What is the classpath for the example java file?  new File(src/main/java/com/abc/MyClass.java) doesn't work

Comment: The classpath is what you are setting when running java (either through the `-cp` command line argument or via the `CLASSPATH` environmental variable

Answer (score -1):

From Java Commons IO, see the FileUtils class.

Comment: for example: com.abc.MyClass.java

How do I get the File for this class?

All the FileUtil methods operate on a File.

Comment: new File(pathname-of-the-file)